# AWS Lambda(NET6): no response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am developing AWS Lambda (NET 6) Web service. I have built, deploy it to AWS, added Gateway endpoints. Then run to test expecting Swagger page. But instead of it I received

```
{"message": "Internal Server Error"}.
```

I have checked the CLoudWatch records: there are all my log records from ConfigureServices, Configure , all my services started, Swagger too. But at the end of logs I see one :

```
Unable to bind to http://localhost:5000 on the IPv6 loopback interface: "Address family not supported by protocol"
```

My be it the reason of the problem? How to detect and fix the reason?

P.S. I have a 2nd Login+Pwd to other region. And I have uploaded the same function (published to Linux-x64 zip). It works fine, I see the Swagger page etc.